# Disable checkstyle for hashCode and equals

Tags: java, coding-style, checkstyle

I need example configuration to totally disable check-style for `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods.

Comment: @shaman whats wrong with matthews solution?

Comment: The problem is that checkstyle tends to perform checks inside the code of augogenerated equals() and hashcode() methods, which usually violate our coding conventions

Comment: We hit the same problem. For example, the cyclomatic complexity check often flags the `equals()` method due to the large number of `&&` operators in the result expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not a direct answer to your question, but Lombok really shines on avoiding this sort of boilerplate code: http://projectlombok.org

For this case, you can just annotate your classes with:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of="id")
```

or

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(excludes={"these","fields","wont","be","compared"})
```

Haven't tested it against checkstyle, though...

Answer (score 3):

See EqualsHashCode in [Checkstyle 5.5: Coding Config](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html). Just remove the

```
<module name="EqualsHashCode"/>
```

from your checkstyle configuration file, or do it through the Eclipse plugin. But I would ask myself why you're doing this. Bad implementation of equals() and hashCode() is a common source of errors, so be very careful before you do this.

Comment: I am using eclipe to generate it. I know that I need to disable it from checkstyle xml - the question is how. I would like to disable every check on those methods.

Comment: @Matthew Farwell: I'd argue that overreliance on *hashCode()* and *equals* is an even worse disease. Appeal to authority with a quote from *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch: *"There is simply no way to extend an instantiable class and add an aspect while preserving the equals contract"*. This is a very well known, very well documented, and very real issue. One could argue that a default hashCode/equals throwing an exception is saner than trying to implement a "correct" equals/hashCode.  Martin Odersky on the subject: http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html

Comment: @Matthew Farwell: now of course I *do* use *hashCode* and *equals* and all the great collections depending on these...  But I wanted to point out how outrageously difficult this really is in the face of inheritance: the *canEqual* method explanation in that Artima article (and the restrictions it imposes) was an eye-opener to me : )   Definitely not something that checkstyle verifies ; )

Answer (score 2):

Checkstyle in eclipse. Open Windows -> Preferences -> Checkstyle.

If you are using the default configuration, copy to a different name, select the copied one and click configure. Search for equals and select 'Equals and Hashcode' under coding problems. Uncheck all the enabled ones that you dont need.

Hit ok and set as default.

Comment: I'm sure hudson runs the checkstyle against a particular set of rules. Just replace those rules with the ones you generate using the above approach.